# Dynamic value for variable stored in enum

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, enums

I have a `enum`:

```
enum Role {
    static let Employee = “employee”
    static let Manager = // it depends on other variable values
}
```

As you see above, the `Manager` role value is depending on other values, how to make it so that I can pass parameters to `Role` for `Manager` to create the right value for `Manager`?

(If it is impossible to do with `enum`, what could be the alternative way?)

Comment: Please review enum syntax in Swift 3 and provide more details about your problem

Comment: @ĐinhQuangHiếu that is valid Swift 3 syntax, OP is not declaring enum cases, only storing static variables inside an enum.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign another variable's value to a variable inside an `enum` just as you would with a `class` or `struct`.

```
let managerName = "manager"

enum Role {
    static let Employee = "employee"
    static let Manager = managerName
}

print(Role.Manager) //prints manager
```

The only thing you cannot assign dynamically is the `RawValue` of a `case` of the `enum`. `RawValue`s have to be literals.

```
enum Role:String {
    static let Employee = "employee"
    static let Manager = managerName
    case employee, manager = managerName //error: Raw value for enum case must be literal
}
```